# Connect Multiple docker containers using Java Socket Programming

Tags: java, docker

I have two containers connected on same network. I am able to ping containers. I am trying to share data using java socket programming. How can I connect using java and share data between containers.

Below I have attached code for client and server. Both files are running on same host machine and on the same container(ntu-vm-soft40051).HostName is the container ID to whom I have to share data and port I have mapped.

5071de43f576   22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3390->3389/tcp   ntu-vm-soft40051
a6d4bc5dadf0   0.0.0.0:4848->22/tcp             soft40051-simple-container1

```
public class Client
{
   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
       
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("a6d4bc5dadf0", 22))
        {
            //InputStream input=socket.getInputStream();
           
            //BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            //TODO add code here
 
            //String line;
            //System.out.println("Print received the following message:\n");
           
            //while((line=reader.readLine())!= null)
            {
                //System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
 
            System.out.println("Server not found: " + ex.getMessage());
 
        } catch (IOException ex) {
 
            System.out.println("I/O error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Server {
   
    //socket server port on which it will listen
   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        int port = 22;
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port))
        {
 
           
           
 
            while (true)
            {
               
                //ServerSocket serversoc=new ServerSocket(port);
                Socket socket=serverSocket.accept();
                //System.out.println("Hi");
                System.out.println("New Client is connected");
               
                //OutputStream output= socket.getOutputStream();
               
                //PrintWriter writer=new PrintWriter(output, true);
                //writer.println("Hello this is a message sent by the server!");
                //writer.println("This is second string sent by server");
                //writer.println("Third string");
                //writer.println(new Date().toString());
            }
 
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Server exception: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
   
}
```

Comment: How are you launching the two containers?  Where does the magic hex hostname come from?  (I don't think you can ever use a container ID as a hostname.)  What error are you getting, from which process?  Can you [edit] the question to remove the unnecessary commented code, leaving a [mcve]?

Comment: Does the same code run outside of Docker? If so, you could narrow the issue to being a Docker networking issue.

Comment: I am just answer a question like this, and give a example code all. You can visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74756501/why-docker-java-server-clients-doesnt-work/74759917#74759917