# Why Docker (Java Server-Clients) doesn`t work?

Tags: java, .net, docker, ip

I am learning Docker now. And i have faced with a problem: I have been practiced Docker Compose and got a problem with creating containers. The task:
There is a Server (Java). The server is very simple. It is just waiting messages from clients and printing them. There are not any threads or something like that. It is not what this app about. The code of the server:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Server was started!");
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8899)) {
            while (true) {
                try (Socket client = serverSocket.accept()) {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                    String line = reader.readLine();
                    System.out.println(client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " - " + line);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Dops");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are two clients. Also Java language. They are also very simple:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;


class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
           
        
        String ip = "app_server";
        while (true){
        try (Socket socket = new Socket(ip, 8899)) {
            System.out.println("An attempt...");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            String message = "Hello from client_1\n";
            writer.write(message);
            writer.flush();
            System.out.println("The package was sent!");
        }
        }
        
    }
}
```

The second client is totaly the same, but the message is "Hello from client_2\n".

So the idea is to create 3 containers (Server, Client#1, Client#2). And clients have to send a message to the server every 10 seconds. I have tried that on my computer and everithing was fine. It worked perfectly. But I used definite IP 192.168.7.121 in Client app code.

So I created folders:

[image]

Dockerfile from Client 1:

```
FROM openjdk:11

WORKDIR /app_client1

COPY . .

RUN javac Client.java

CMD [ "java", "Client" ]
```

Dockerfile from Client 2:

```
FROM openjdk:11

WORKDIR /app_client2

COPY . .

RUN javac Client.java

CMD [ "java", "Client" ]
```

Docker file from Server

```
FROM openjdk:11

WORKDIR /app_server

COPY . .

RUN javac Server.java

CMD [ "java", "Server" ]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app_server:
    build: ./app_server
  app_client1:
    build: ./app_client1  
  app_client2:
    build: ./app_client2
```

And after i had typed the comand "docker-compose up" to terminal, a got this:

```
PS D:\it\dockerNet\docker-compose-app> docker-compose up
[+] Running 3/3
 - Container docker-compose-app-app_server-1   Cr...                                             0.6s
 - Container docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  C...                                              0.6s
 - Container docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  C...                                              0.6s
Attaching to docker-compose-app-app_client1-1, docker-compose-app-app_client2-1, docker-compose-app-app_server-1
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  | Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  |     at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  |     at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:454)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:231)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  |     at Client.main(Client.java:15)
docker-compose-app-app_server-1   | /bin/sh: 1: [java,: not found
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1 exited with code 1
docker-compose-app-app_server-1 exited with code 127
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  | Exception in thread "main" java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  |     at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  |     at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:454)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:231)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  |     at Client.main(Client.java:15)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1 exited with code 1
```

And now there are two questions:

1. Can I change Server IP address by the service name "app_server". Regarding youtube tutorials it is probably possible. If I can`t use that How I suposse to know IP address of the Server before containers creating?
2. I do not understand why i can not create containers. Where is mistake and what is wrong? What I have done wrong?

I will be very gratefull for you help!

---

update:

According to advice in comments bellow, I changed code in both Clients to avoid possible exceptions. Now they look like:

```
import java.io.IOException;


class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("TEST");
        
    }
}
```

But I still have error:

```
PS D:\it\dockerNet\docker-compose-app> docker-compose up
[+] Running 3/0
 - Container docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  C...                                              0.0s 
 - Container docker-compose-app-app_server-1   Cr...                                             0.0s 
 - Container docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  C...                                              0.0s 
Attaching to docker-compose-app-app_client1-1, docker-compose-app-app_client2-1, docker-compose-app-app_server-1
docker-compose-app-app_server-1   | /bin/sh: 1: [java,: not found
docker-compose-app-app_server-1 exited with code 127
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  | Exception in thread "main" java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  | Exception in thread "main" java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  |     at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  |     at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  |     at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  |     at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:454)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:454)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:231)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:231)
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1  |     at Client.main(Client.java:15)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1  |     at Client.main(Client.java:15)
docker-compose-app-app_client1-1 exited with code 1
docker-compose-app-app_client2-1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: Your containers are being created.  You can tell by the output.  They are just not talking to one another.  I am not the best at docker myself, but I believe that you need to open the 8899 port on your server.  And the ip address inside of docker will for sure be different in your containers then on your local/host computer.  BUT, looking at Socket, socket can also work by host name, and docker is quite good at working with host names.  Give that a try if you can instead of ip addresses.

Comment: Thanks! But then I got new questions. If my containers have been successfully created. Why using command "docker ps" I do not see them? Using command "docker ps - a" I can see that containers status are "Exited". In server app code I use while(true) and the app have not  to be closed even if it doesn`t get eny messages from clients. It has to wait for messages.

Comment: And about port, is it port normally open or closed in docker container? Regarding IP, IP address I used only during testing apps on my local/host computer. For docker I changed code of clients, and tried to connect to server by service name "appServer"

Comment: I am unsure why the server would be exiting, but the clients are exiting because they are throwing an exception that isn't caught and that causes the main method to exit.  If you put a catch statement with your client's try statement, they would keep running.

Comment: @hooknc I can check that. I edited the question and added update information. So, I deleted all rows connected with Soccets from my Clients classes. Now they do not have to throw exceptions. But I still have problems with creating containers. Please look to new information in my question.

Comment: Also error log has a row "docker-compose-app-app_server-1   | /bin/sh: 1: [java,: not found". And it bother me, why this command doesn`t work? Why "not found". Is something bad in row witch CMD command?

Comment: Looking closely at the second set of error messages, the server fails because it can't find java `/bin/sh: 1: [java,: not found`.  First and foremost, I would get that figured out.  Next, I would try just with one docker container, that being the server and see if you could have a client running on your host contact that docker hosted server.

Comment: The `[java,` is usually a symptom that your CMD isn't actually a JSON array.  Double-check that you have the punctuation correct and that you have ordinary ASCII spaces U+0020 and double quotes U+0022 (what you have in the question seems right, but double-check locally).

Comment: I have been able to deploy (more or less the same) code on my local machine and I was able to get your applications to work together.  I was wrong on the port numbers in the docker-compose file.  The port numbers are only needed if you want external services to talk to your docker containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SERVER - MYSERVER.java

```
package org.example;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MYSERVER {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        System.out.println("Server was started!");
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8899)) {
            while (true) {
                try (Socket client = serverSocket.accept()) {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                    String line = reader.readLine();
                    System.out.println(client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " - " + line);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Dops");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

## CLIENT - MYCLIENT.java

```
package org.example;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MYCLIENT {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        String ip = "localhost";
        if (args.length > 0) ip= args[0];
        System.out.println("ip="+ip);
        int no = 1;
        if (args.length > 1) no= Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        String whoami="client #"+no;
        System.out.println("whoami="+whoami);
        while (true){
            try (Socket socket = new Socket(ip, 8899)) {
                System.out.println("An attempt...");
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                String message = "Hello from "+whoami+" at "+ Calendar.getInstance().getTime() +"\n";
                writer.write(message);
                writer.flush();
                System.out.println("The package was sent!");
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 //do nothing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## BUILD JAVA TO EXECUTE JAR

- MYCLIENT-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
- MYSERVER-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

## HOST TEST

- Open Terminal 1: `java -jar MYSERVER-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`
- Open Terminal 2: `java -jar MYCLIENT-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar localhost 1`
- Open Terminal 3: `java -jar MYCLIENT-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar localhost 2`
- Open Terminal 4: `java -jar MYCLIENT-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar localhost 3`

## MY_SERVER_CLIENT

```
├── docker-compose.yml
├── MYCLIENT
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── MYCLIENT-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
└── MYSERVER
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── MYSERVER-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

### MYSERVER - Dockerfile

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17.0.5_8-jre-ubi9-minimal
EXPOSE 8899
WORKDIR /app
COPY MYSERVER-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "app.jar"]
```

### MYSERVER - build command

```
docker build -t demoserver:1.0.0 .
       
docker tag demoserver:1.0.0 demoserver:latest
```

### MYCLIENT - Dockerfile

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17.0.5_8-jre-ubi9-minimal
WORKDIR /app
COPY MYCLIENT-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "app.jar"]
CMD ["locahost","1"]
```

### MYCLIENT - build command

```
docker build -t democlient:1.0.0 .
       
docker tag democlient:1.0.0 democlient:latest
```

## TEST

### Test Server - demoserver

- Open terminal 1: `docker run -it demoserver`
- Open terminal 2: `docker ps`
- terminal 2: `docker inspect demoserver-container-id`

Get container ip like `"IPAddress": "172.17.0.2"`

### Test Client - client

- Open terminal 3: `docker run -it democlient 172.17.0.2 1`
- Open terminal 4: `docker run -it democlient 172.17.0.2 2`
- Open terminal 5: `docker run -it democlient 172.17.0.2 3`
- Open terminal 6: `docker run -it democlient 172.17.0.2 4`

### See Terminal 1

FIND

```
$ docker run -it demoserver
Hello world!
Server was started!
172.17.0.3 - Hello from client #1 at Sun Dec 11 10:07:47 GMT 2022
172.17.0.3 - Hello from client #1 at Sun Dec 11 10:07:57 GMT 2022
172.17.0.4 - Hello from client #2 at Sun Dec 11 10:08:02 GMT 2022
172.17.0.3 - Hello from client #1 at Sun Dec 11 10:08:07 GMT 2022
172.17.0.4 - Hello from client #2 at Sun Dec 11 10:08:12 GMT 2022
172.17.0.3 - Hello from client #1 at Sun Dec 11 10:08:17 GMT 2022
172.17.0.5 - Hello from client #3 at Sun Dec 11 10:08:17 GMT 2022
172.17.0.4 - Hello from client #2 at Sun Dec 11 10:08:22 GMT 2022
```

## Last Step Create `docker-compose.yml`

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  demoserver:
    image: demoserver

  democlient1:
    image: democlient
    command: demoserver 1
    depends_on:
      - demoserver

  democlient2:
    image: democlient
    command: demoserver 2
    depends_on:
      - demoserver

  democlient3:
    image: democlient
    command: demoserver 3
    depends_on:
      - demoserver
```

### Run docker compose

- Open terminal: `docker compose up`

  $ docker compose up
  [+] Running 4/0
  ⠿ Container my_server_client-demoserver-1   Created                       0.0s
  ⠿ Container my_server_client-democlient3-1  Created                       0.0s
  ⠿ Container my_server_client-democlient1-1  Created                       0.0s
  ⠿ Container my_server_client-democlient2-1  Created                       0.0s
  Attaching to my_server_client-democlient1-1, my_server_client-democlient2-1, my_server_client-democlient3-1, my_server_client-demoserver-1
  my_server_client-demoserver-1   | Hello world!
  my_server_client-demoserver-1   | Server was started!
  my_server_client-democlient2-1  | Hello world!
  my_server_client-democlient2-1  | ip=demoserver
  my_server_client-democlient2-1  | whoami=client #2
  my_server_client-democlient2-1  | An attempt...
  my_server_client-democlient3-1  | Hello world!
  my_server_client-democlient3-1  | ip=demoserver
  my_server_client-democlient1-1  | Hello world!
  my_server_client-democlient3-1  | whoami=client #3
  my_server_client-democlient2-1  | The package was sent!
  my_server_client-democlient1-1  | ip=demoserver
  my_server_client-demoserver-1   | 172.18.0.3 - Hello from client #2 at Sun Dec 11 10:29:55 GMT 2022
  my_server_client-democlient1-1  | whoami=client #1
  my_server_client-democlient3-1  | An attempt...
  my_server_client-democlient1-1  | An attempt...
  my_server_client-democlient3-1  | The package was sent!
  my_server_client-demoserver-1   | 172.18.0.4 - Hello from client #3 at Sun Dec 11 10:29:55 GMT 2022
  my_server_client-democlient1-1  | The package was sent!
  my_server_client-demoserver-1   | 172.18.0.5 - Hello from client #1 at Sun Dec 11 10:29:55 GMT 2022

### Run docker compose again

- Open terminal: `docker compose up --scale app_client1=10`

## DIY

```
services:
  demoserver:
    image: demoserver

  democlient1:
    image: democlient
  ...
```

Change `image` to `build` yourself.

## Do one thing at a time

- Step 1. test java part, server , client
- Step 2. package server, client as execute jar
- Step 3. test it on host, not on docker
- Step 4. pack server to docker image
- Step 5. test server use docker image, but test client on host
- Step 6. pack client to docker image
- Step 7. test server image and client image
- Step 8. build `docker-compose.yml`
- Step 9. test docker compose

I am used to cutting the problem into many parts, then solving each part, testing each part, and finally combining each part
But each part has been tested, so I can know what the message is if an error occurs, which part is wrong, and how to deal with it.