# java error connecting two devices with socket (public ip)

Tags: java, sockets, port, forwarding

i'm almost a new java programmer (started at 5 month ago) and i want to connect two program over internet but i get some error that's i can't fix.

i've tried alot. i told to my friend to ping my public ip in cmd and he did and it worked fine. with that the java client did'nt work either.

after that, I looked for another answer on stackoverflow, then i found a comment that said you have to do **port forwarding** . i did port forwarding and it still gives an error.

Client

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        
        Socket s = new Socket("151.245.38.21",113);
        
          while (true){

          } 
        }
    }
```

SERVER

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class SERVER{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{



        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(113); //the port that i used in port forwarding

        Socket s = ss.accept();

        System.out.println("Connected!");

    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(ss);

        
        while (true){
        
        } 
    }
}
```

error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:585)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:507)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:287)
    at Client.main(Client.java:7)
```

Comment: How you do the port forwarding?

Comment: Are you sure that it works?

Comment: Port 113 is part of the [reserved ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports), use a port >1024. However your issue is somewhere else. Double check that the ip address you are using is actually your public IP address. Also check again that you forwarded your port to the machine where the server is running. Also make sure your server is actually running and that no firewall blocks the port.

Comment: I do not *feel insecure* But You answer a question of someone else to me

Comment: @providerZ there is no thread pool involved here. Also no thread executor is being interrupted. The only issue is a very simple `ConnectException` that happens because of the network topology. Your comment still has nothing to do with the question and there is nothing to support your claims. Bringing up the word "insecure" does not make you look more professional.

Comment: @f1sh do i have to port forward on the server or Client? i have the server and client run in on one devise.

Comment: @MASEH your server application is running on a machine is behind a router, right? The port forwarding needs to be done on the router so that requests to that port are forwarded to the server machine.

Comment: @f1sh i do'nt get the "server application is running on a machine is behind a router" . the server is in my laptop and my laptop is connected to a wifi.

Comment: @MASEH there is a device that forwards your wifi signals to the internet and vice versa. That device is a router. That device needs to forward incoming requests on that port to your laptop. If you have no access to the management interface of that router, you cannot forward the port. Where else did you try port forwarding!?

Comment: @f1sh i did that in router setting.

Comment: @MASEH , Before dealing with network or environmental issues, it is generally necessary to complete the Client App and Server App first. Then at least test the connection locally. After that is the Internet connection test.

Comment: @MASEH , example code (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74756501/why-docker-java-server-clients-doesnt-work/74759917#74759917) , Ignore Docker description.